# Replication with one side insert but two side update

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have server A and server B.
I want server A can see data and changes on specific article on server B .
But server B just see its own data .
And also I want to update server B's data on both servers and data remain consistent.
I want to prohibit the server B to see server A data
As simple word I want replication with one way insert on subscriber and two way update on publisher data on both servers.
Is it possible ?
If it is how?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be achieved by using Merge Replication in conjunction with article filters.  Merge Replication will allow for bidirectional synchronization and row/column filters can provide a means to prohibit Server B from accessing Server A data.

Have a look at [Merge Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx) and [Filter Published Data](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151775.aspx).